# ライブドアブログ（RSS1.0）のフィードから日付を取り出したい

Tags: android, java

Androidにて、RSSを取得するプログラムです。
http://www.panzee.biz/archives/3255　こちらのサイトにあるコードですが
このままですとライブドアブログの形式で取得できません。

```
 RSSは
<link>
http://blog.livedoor.jp/------.html
</link>
<description/>
<dc:creator>aatyu</dc:creator>
<dc:date>2016-01-02T22:35:31+09:00</dc:date>
<dc:subject>ハード・業界</dc:subject>
```

上記の形式です。下記コードの日付取得の部分を
　　　　}else if(tag.equals("dc:date")){//日付別バーション
と変更してみましたが取得できませんでした。
    tag.contains("date")
    tag.equals(":date")
これらでもダメでした。（結果がnullのまま）

```
    // XMLをパースする

public RssListAdapter parseXml(InputStream is) throws IOException,
        XmlPullParserException {
    XmlPullParser parser = Xml.newPullParser();
    try {
        parser.setInput(is, null);
        int eventType = parser.getEventType();
        Item currentItem = null;
        while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            String tag = null;
            switch (eventType) {
            case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                tag = parser.getName();
                if (tag.equals("item")) {
                    currentItem = new Item();
                } else if (currentItem != null) {
                    if (tag.equals("title")) {
                        currentItem.setTitle(parser.nextText());
                    } else if (tag.equals("author")) {
                        currentItem.setSite((parser.nextText()));
                    } else if (tag.equals("pubDate")) {
                        currentItem.setDate((parser.nextText()));
                    }
//                      else if (tag.equals("description")) {
//                              currentItem.setDescription(parser.nextText());
//                      }
                }
                break;
            case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                tag = parser.getName();
                if (tag.equals("item")) {
                    mAdapter.add(currentItem);
                }
                break;
            }
            eventType = parser.next();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return mAdapter;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

}else if(tag.equals("date")) {

で取得できました